# Choopy Video Playback in a popup using Artiss Youtube Embed

Tags: plugins, videos, youtube

I'm using [Artiss Youtube Embed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-embed/) to embed youtube videos on my site which works great because it allows me to control all the parameters for the video player. My issue is that when the video has choppy playback when it's playing in a popup window. I allow users to click on thumbnails on the homepage and then I use SimpleModal Jquery plugin to popup the video from the post. I tested a video from youtube using their iframe embed code and it worked perfectly. So something with this plugin is causing the choppy playback which only occurs in the popup. It works normally on a single post page. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: This is a JavaScript/jQuery and window mode issue, not a WordPress issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Artiss I figured out this was a problem with the Windows Mode setting. By default it's set to opaque but for it not to conflict with video in a popup